# C: Why does snprintf only writes 4 characters to my variable?

Tags: c, printf, malloc

So I'm trying to return a variable that contains a string with some parameters determined inside the function.

```
char* render(my parameters)
```

I'm declaring my variable like this:

```
char *string = malloc(sizeof(char) * 50);
```

This is an excerpt of my function:

```
switch(INST_OPCODE){
        case 0x00:
            inst->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen("add") + 1));
            inst->name = "add";
            inst->type = 1;
            snprintf(string, sizeof(string), "add r%d, r%d, r%d", INST_RD, INST_RA, INST_TYPE_A_RB);
            printf("add r%d, r%d, r%d", INST_RD, INST_RA, INST_TYPE_A_RB);
            return string;
        case 0x01:
            inst->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen("rsub") + 1));
            inst->name = "rsub";
            inst->type = 1;
            snprintf(string, sizeof(string), "rsub r%d, r%d, r%d", INST_RD, INST_RA, INST_TYPE_A_RB);
            printf("rsub r%d, r%d, r%d", INST_RD, INST_RA, INST_TYPE_A_RB);
            return string;
```

The printf works fine and it's just for debugging purposes, but when I print the returned variable in a file with:

```
fprintf(fd, "%s\n", render(my parameters));
```

It writes only 4 characters and then literally memory garbage, one example:

```
addi-ž
```

Please give me some insight of what's going on here.

Comment: Use `strlen(string)` not `sizeof(string)`

Comment: `sizeof(string)` returns the size of the `char*` pointer itself, not the size of the allocated data that `string` is pointing at.

Comment: You are setting `inst->name` to the malloc'd value, but right after, you set that same variable to the address of the string literal, "add".  That assignment is not a string copy, though it looks like what you meant.

Comment: `inst->name = malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen("add") + 1));` is immediately overwritten by `inst->name = "add";`

Comment: Where does `inst` have any effect on `string`?  I don't see it in the `snprintf()`.

Comment: `inst->name` just have to do with the parameters of the functon and not with the snprintf itself. 
When allocating the string, I still don't know the size of whats being saved, I just know it will be always <50 sizeof(char).
Thank you.

Comment: @Isaiah: the array pointed to by `string` is uninitialized (returned by `malloc`), `strlen(string)` invokes undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

4 is the size of the pointer on 32 bit systems, it's 8 on 64 bit systems. For pointers, sizeof always return the size of the pointer and not the size of the data it points to.

Better yet, use `sizeof(char) * num_characters_in_string`. Use `sizeof(char) * 50` in this case.

Of course, `sizeof(char)` always equals 1, so you can omit that part if you want.

The reason you get garbage is because some data is not initialized (due to the size parameter). Debuggers automatically initialize everthing to 0, so that is why it would work while debugging. Outside of debugging, it can start with any value.

Finally, the `printf` statement works because you didn't print out your return value. It might've been more prudent to write `printf("%s", string);` rather than repeat your snprintf line. (Remember -- snprintf only printed up to n characters, so the rest of the characters were left with their garbage values).

Comment: `4 is the size of any pointer`. What about the 64bit machines? :D

Comment: Not `strlen` either because `string` might not yet be initialized.

Comment: You should use `sizeof(char) * 50` (the buffer size). Better yet, subtract `1` to make sure the resulting string will be 0-terminated.

Comment: @Isaiah: Even if it's "initialized", `strlen` won't return the *buffer* size, but the size of the string currently contained by the buffer.

Comment: In any case, `sizeof` is faster because evaluated in the preprocessing phase, whereas `strlen` is evaluated at runtime.

Comment: @EugeniuRosca: It's faster, but it gets you a result that is wrong for your purpose! What's the point of getting useless things *fast*?

Comment: @Eugeniu Rosca: no, `sizeof` is almost always evaluated at compile time, not at preprocessing time, and in some cases at runtime, but it is always very quick.  `strlen` of string constants is usually evaluated at compile also by modern compilers.

Comment: @mastov: Only if you can use both, I pointed the prefered one. Cheers.

Comment: This answer only explains the 4 characters, but does not cover the garbage.  `snprintf()` is documented to use a terminating null, which should preclude the garbage.

Comment: But in this case, sizeof and strlen are both wrong.  (And, in general, they're never equivalent anyway.)  The string has nothing in it yet, snprintf is about to create a string, so you need to tell snprintf how much it's allowed to write, or in this case, 50.

Comment: @chqrlie: My bad. sizeof is evaluated at compile-time, not by the preprocessor.

Comment: @mastov: no need to subtract `1`, `snprintf` takes the size of the buffer and stores the `'\0'` inside the buffer, unless the size is specified as `0`.

Comment: @chqrlie: Yes, I just realized that, too. I had confused it with the more dangerous "strncpy".

Comment: @Isaiah,  Right.  I'm saying there is more to debug here.

Comment: @mastov: correct! absolutely dangerous "strncpy" must be avoided always.

Comment: Ok, its fully corrected and I removed the part about strlen. I also explained why he got garbage characters using sizeof(string). Thanks for the comments.

Comment: @chqrlie && @mastov: You probably refered to `strcpy`, not to `strncpy`, as a dangerous thing to be avoided.

Comment: @Isaiah: I don't think your theory explains the garbage. "some data is not initialized" is not enough. The array `string` is initialized up to the 0-termination character, which should  be enough not to print garbage.

Comment: @EugeniuRosca: No, we don't - https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2013/04/03/stop-using-strncpy-already/

Comment: @Eugeniu Rosca: no, we do not. `strcpy()` should be used carefully, but `strncpy()` has non intuitive semantics which make it very error prone. Among other peculiarities, if the source string is the same length or longer than the destination array size, the destination will not be `'\0'` terminated.  Many unsuspecting programmers get this wrong and misuse this function. It is best avoided completely.

Comment: @chqrlie && mastov: thanks for the explanations and link!

Answer (score 2):

In your case the second argument to `snprintf` needs to be 50, *not* sizeof(string).

Comment: WHY WAS THIS ACCEPTED? Firstly, my answer is the same, yet better. Secondly, my answer was posted first.

Comment: @Isaiah: You still have that dangerous `strlen` in your answer that can screw things up.

Comment: @Isaiah your answer had the problem with the strlen, and now that's corrected is the best answer, your explanation is now completely correct. It was assuming the size of the pointer and not the size that I allocated for it. Thank you so much to both!

Comment: @Isaiah: the other concern I had with your answer was your instruction to multiply by `sizeof(char)`.  As others pointed out, `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1, so multiplying by it isn't necessary in this case.  You can do it if you like, but telling others that they have to may confuse them.